# Test the hypothesis test of Constant Return to scale for a cobb-douglas function:

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statsmodels, patsy

I use scipy project packages like numpy and pandas + statsmodel for some econometrics work, like regression and now I want a  test that show β1+β2=1.

My formula is : $ Ln(Q_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Ln(L_i) + \beta_2 Ln(K_i) $

I know in stata I have to use this code but in python I don't what is the best way to test β1+β2=1:

```
test ln(K)+ln(L)=1
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to work with latex here I try http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I think in statsmodels they usually use patsy for formulas?

Comment: Linear hypothesis test on the parameters can be done with t_test or f_test or wald_test methods of the results instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohnE and JseBold[Slides](http://jseabold.net/presentations/seabold_pydata2012.html#slide23) I found the way how  test OLS parameters and  telt linear combination of OLS parameters Using `statsmodels` package, it works with `patsy` formula and it's very easy, Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pn
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

\\reading stata data file:
dp4 = pn.read_stata('datapset4.dta')

\\Rergession:
formula = 'Ln(output) ~ Ln(labor) +Ln(capital)   '
cb= smf.ols(formula, data = dp4).fit()

\\Hypothesis Test for H0: "beta1 + beta 2 = 1"
print(cb.t_test("Ln(labor) +Ln(capital)=1"))



                           Test for Constraints                             
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c0             0.9787      0.063     -0.340      0.737         0.850     1.108
==============================================================================
```

So for testing a linear combination of parameters you just need write patsy formula for the variable and linear combination you want, and put it in t_test or f_test method of your regression:

```
cb.t_test("Ln(labor) +Ln(capital)=1")
```

And for testing a hypothesis about  a parameter you just need to write the equation you want to test within quotations, for example if you want test beta1 = 1/2,(beta1 as coefficient of Ln(labor)) you just need to write this code:

```
print(cb.t_test("Ln(labor)=0.5"))
                             Test for Constraints                             
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c0             0.6030      0.126      0.818      0.422         0.343     0.863
==============================================================================
```